# Which folder should I upload to?

Tags: ftp

I have connected to my server via FTP. However, once I enter the server there are some folders and I'm not too sure which to upload to. The folders are:

```
etc
mail
perl5
public_ftp
public_html
-cgi-bin
tmp
www
```

Comment: What are you uploading? A website? What about the `www` folder then? Consult your server's or hoster's documentation.

Comment: Yeah, a website. THanks, I will try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your going to want to upload to public_html this will be the folder that displays your files on your website address/url